# Why my bootstrap responsive table not shrink

Tags: html, .net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Work on asp.net mvc5.Why not my responsive table shrink?when i re-size browser than scroll apprear.

my table syntax is bellow:

```
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div><!-- end col-12 -->
```

How to make my table shrink.

[image]

Comment: that's how the table-responsive class works

Comment: From documentation - by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: remove the table-responsive from the outer div - But from my experiences table-responsive is the best way to go, then user can easily read all the data by scrolling - for tables with lots of columns the data becomes unreadable when table-responsive is removed.

Comment: you can also add the table-condensed class to remove the padding in the table cells

Answer (score 1):

This code appears to be working as expected.

`table-responsive` allows the  table to overflow freely so the content pushes it to the maximum size. If this is too wide, add a custom class with a max width to your liking.

For alternative responsive table approaches, check out: http://www.webadvanced.com/news/painless-responsive-tables

PS `col-12` isn't in Bootstrap and `col-sm-12` is effective for all larger view ports making `col-lg-12` redundant.